# Easy way to HTML encode data returned from a json-serializing web service

Tags: .net, web-services, json

I have a web service, with a method like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
public object GetPeople()
{
     return PeopleRepository.GetPeople();
}
```

The problem with this approach is that all the people's properties are not html encoded, resulting in a potential security problem.

Assuming I want to avoid manually calling HttpUtility.HtmlEncode on each property, what is the simplest way to ensure that all data returned from the web service is html encoded?

Answer (score 0):

possible duplicate: [HtmlEncode my JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056539/htmlencode-in-my-ashx)

on the other hand, you can use reflection to iterate over the properties and encode them like shown here [Iterating over class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571982/iterating-over-class-properties)